# getting error trying to test service using a get request

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-http, ballerina-vscode-plugin

I'm new to Ballerina and am encountering an error. I have made a service and am using Postman and the terminal using the `curl` command, but I keep getting this error:

```shell
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

Here is my code. It is correct if I'm not mistaken

```ballerina
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;


type User record {
    readonly string id;
    string name;
    int age;
};

table<User> key(id) userTable = table[];

service /on new http:Listener(8080) {
    resource function post createUser(User user) returns string {
        userTable.add(user);    
        //if you want to use io  
        io:println("user saved sucesfully: " + user.toString());
        return "user saved successfully";
    }

    resource function get getAllUsers()returns User[] {
        return  userTable.toArray();
    }
}
```

these are the `curl` commands I've used

```shell
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id": "1", "name": "John", "age": 30}' http://localhost:8080/createUser
```

```shell
curl http://localhost:8080/getAllUsers
```

Comment: I just tried your code, and the curl commands with Ballerina Swan Lake Update 7.2 on Mac work as expected. What is your environment (OS and Ballerina version)? Also, can you share the CLI output as well?